# Go: "stat hello.go: no such file or directory"

Tags: macos, go, osx-yosemite

Just installed Go on Mac OS X, Yosemite Version 10.10.3, as explained in the [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) page of the official website:

> **Mac OS X package installer**
>
> Download the package file, open it, and follow the prompts to install
>   the Go tools. The package installs the Go distribution to
>   `/usr/local/go`.
>
> The package should put the `/usr/local/go/bin` directory in your PATH
>   environment variable. You may need to restart any open Terminal
>   sessions for the change to take effect.

I am now in the *Test your installation* section, which states:

> Check that Go is installed correctly by building a simple program, as
>   follows.
>
> Create a file named `hello.go` and put the following program in it:
>
> ```
> package main
>
> import "fmt"
>
> func main() {
>     fmt.Printf("hello, world\n") }
> ```
>
> Then run it with the go tool:
>
> ```
> $ go run hello.go
> hello, world
> ```
>
> If you see the "hello, world" message then your Go installation is
>   working.

So, I created a `hello.go` file and, since I could not (ie: did not know how to) access the `/usr/local/go/bin` directory, I saved it on my desktop.

Obviously, I got the following error message:

```
stat hello.go: no such file or directory
```

So, where should I save my Go files to be able to run them?

**UPDATE**: after some research, I stumbled upond this video, explaining how to set the GOPATH.

If I want my Go workspace to be in `user/code/go`, how should I write my `export GOPATH=` command?

Comment: What happens when you run "go version"?

Comment: I get `go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Following the explanation of Andrew Gerrand in *[Writing, building, installing, and testing Go code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsL89YtqCs)*, I configured my Go workspace as follows:

**1. Create workspace**

First, since I want my Go code to be in `my_user_name/code/go`, I started by creating the corresponding folder:

```
$ cd code
$ mkdir go
```

**2. Setup GOPATH**

Then I configured the GOPATH:

```
$ cd
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/code/go
$ cd code/go
```

**3. Add files to workspace**

Last, I manually (through the Finder) moved my hello.go file into the workspace and ran:

```
$ go run hello.go
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using docker compose *up/down* to build image. You need to run

```
docker compose build
```

after changes in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was as simple as right clicking the file, and then clicking 'open in integrated terminal.' Then, to run your file type 'go run *filename*.go'

Answer (score -1):

The `GOPATH` and `PATH` environment variables

The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It defaults to a directory named go inside your home directory (`$HOME/go`).

If you really want to change your GOPATH to something else add GOPATH to your `shell/bash/zsh` initialization file `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

`export GOPATH=/something-else`

Add `GOPATH/bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable so you can run Go programs anywhere.

`export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin`